# Describe each table's columns

Tags: mysql, sql, columnsorting

I'm doing table analysis to understand each table column in a database. Currently, I know how to list all the tables details.

```sql
select
    TABLE_SCHEMA ,
    TABLE_NAME ,
    TABLE_TYPE ,
    TABLE_ROWS
from
    information_schema.TABLES t
where
    TABLE_NAME like '%site%'
    and TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

This will result in defining table schema, table name and table rows.

[image]

How can I do the same but using `DESCRIBE` to list all table columns?

Comment: You may be looking for information_schema.columns perhaps joined to information_schema.tables https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html

Comment: yes, I would like to that for much details by joining those two query case. So far, the answer below has help me. Thankss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `information_schema.COLUMNS` to get all the fields returned by describe command.

Try:

```
select TABLE_SCHEMA as 'database',
       TABLE_NAME as 'table',
       COLUMN_NAME as 'Field',
       DATA_TYPE as 'Type',
       IS_NULLABLE as 'Null',
       COLUMN_KEY as 'Key',
       COLUMN_DEFAULT as 'Default',
       EXTRA as 'Extra' 
from information_schema.COLUMNS;
```

*Note*. Add specific condition if you want to limit the search for specific schema or table like:

```
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your_schema' AND TABLE_NAME='your_table_name'
```

**EDIT**
Tested on my server

```
mysql> select TABLE_SCHEMA as 'database',
       TABLE_NAME as 'table',
           COLUMN_NAME as 'Field',
           DATA_TYPE as 'Type',
           IS_NULLABLE as 'Null',
           COLUMN_KEY as 'Key',
           COLUMN_DEFAULT as 'Default',
           EXTRA as 'Extra'
from information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='gesti' AND TABLE_NAME='test_table';
+----------+------------+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| database | table      | Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| gesti    | test_table | id    | int      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| gesti    | test_table | title | longtext | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc test_table;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title | longtext | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Wow, so nice. I guess I didnt study enough topics for query. Thanks a lot, sir =)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use DESCRIBE or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. These statements produces partial information, and sometimes it looks like incorrect one even.

Example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (f1 INT, f2 INT, f3 INT, f4 INT DEFAULT NULL,
>                    PRIMARY KEY (f1, f2),
>                    UNIQUE (f3, f1),
>                    INDEX (f1, f4))
> ```

> ```
> DESC test
> ```
>
> ```
> Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra
> :---- | :------ | :--- | :-- | :------ | :----
> f1    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | null    |      
> f2    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | null    |      
> f3    | int(11) | YES  | MUL | null    |      
> f4    | int(11) | YES  |     | null    |
> ```

> ```
> select TABLE_SCHEMA as 'database',
>        TABLE_NAME as 'table',
>        COLUMN_NAME as 'Field',
>        DATA_TYPE as 'Type',
>        IS_NULLABLE as 'Null',
>        COLUMN_KEY as 'Key',
>        COLUMN_DEFAULT as 'Default',
>        EXTRA as 'Extra' 
> from information_schema.COLUMNS
> WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
> ```
>
> ```
> database      | table | Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra
> :------------ | :---- | :---- | :--- | :--- | :-- | :------ | :----
> db_1611616104 | test  | f1    | int  | NO   | PRI | null    |      
> db_1611616104 | test  | f2    | int  | NO   | PRI | null    |      
> db_1611616104 | test  | f3    | int  | YES  | MUL | null    |      
> db_1611616104 | test  | f4    | int  | YES  |     | null    |
> ```

> ```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE test
> ```
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `test` (
>  `f1` int(11) NOT NULL,
>  `f2` int(11) NOT NULL,
>  `f3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>  `f4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>  PRIMARY KEY (`f1`,`f2`),
>  UNIQUE KEY `f3` (`f3`,`f1`),
>  KEY `f1` (`f1`,`f4`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c82e5144cae8a3174703e5663eb4c788)*

1. The information about the indices provided by both DESCRIBE and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is partial and does not allow to understand what indices exists in the table really.
2. The output of both DESCRIBE and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS does not allow to understand does the default value is NULL or is not set. Moreover, both DESCRIBE and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS shows that the default values for the columns involved into the primary key are NULL.

So only SHOW CREATE TABLE gives you the complete information about the table structure.